# What do the Smoke Flow Advanced settings do?

Tags: physics, smoke-simulation

In the Smoke Flow panel there is a section called Smoke Flow Advanced. In this section you can find mapping fields (Size, Offset). Could you explain the nature of these fields and how they impact the fire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are mapping adjustments for the emission texture (specified just above them in the panel). Size adjust the scale of the texture coordinates, offset translates the coordinates. Depending on your texture, you may find it useful to animate these to give your flame a more realistic patchy/"licking" appearance.

Comment: So size tells how big or small the "elements" of the noise texture are ? I say elements but I am not sure how to call them. Would Size have an impact on how big or small the flames are ?

Comment: About Offset ... you say "translates the coordinates". Could you explain which coordinates ? the x,y or z-coordinates ? does Offset have an impact on the hight of the flames ?

Comment: I am very interested in using these fields for animation ... would that mean give these fields some very random values so that you get a nice patchy/flickering fire ?

Comment: They do not affect the volume, so they are not "fields" per se. They affect where on the emitter the flames are released from. The texture itself supplies the patchy look (using a noise texture like Clouds works well). Size/offset functions just like, say, the mapping node in Cycles. It just moves the texture around the surface.

Comment: I think I understand Size but Offset remains a bit vague for me. Blender says that Offset is "Z-offset of texture mapping".  What Z-offset ?

Comment: Offset simply moves the texture up and down. "Z offset" refers to the texture being moved up/down rather than side to side.

Comment: It seems to me that Size is the most helpful when you want to give your flame a patchy/flickering appearance, is that correct ?